# find: invalid argument `2s' to `-mtime'

Tags: find

This works: `find /home/example -mtime 2`

This doesn't:  `find /home/example -mtime 2s`

Read the man page but looks like I'm doing it right AFAICT.

Comment: In GNU find manpage it says `-mtime n File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.`. Why do you think you can use `s` suffix here? Is it supposed to mean *seconds*?

Comment: Yeah, got my brain wires crossed. I'm trying to use this with rsync which allows the "s" suffix.

Comment: But rsync doesn't provide `-mtime`

Comment: The --find-files options does. That's where I'm getting the error.

Comment: I have rsync 3.2.3 here and `man rsync` doesn't mention --find-files.

Comment: I mean --files-from

Comment: Shit, now I'm confused. I know I saw this is a man page somewhere. Where the hell was it?

Comment: Ugh, dammit. Looked  up `find` on my local mac instead of remote linux box. I'm a fuckwit.

Comment: Indeed, `man find` on FreeBSD mentions `s second`. It's rare case in which BSD implementation has more option that its GNU equivalent.

Comment: Alright, so now my question is how do I find a file on linux younger than 36 hours ago? -mtime seems to only handle whole numbers.

Comment: I guess I have to do -mmin